# Include coordinates in MouseEvent

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent

I have a vector `a[i][j]` with square coordinates.  Every time I click on the square I want get the coordinates.

If i do

```
[...]
a[i][j].mouseClicked(null);
[...]

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
```

This works, but how can i do something like this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e, int x, int y) {
        System.out.println("X: "+x+", Y: "+y);
    }
```

If I instead use

```
a[i][j].mouseClicked(null,j,i);
```

I get a compile time error:

> "is not abstract and does not override abstract method `mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)` in `java.awt.event.MouseListener`"

Is this possible?

Comment: Please also include the error.

Comment: the error is the red line under "null"

Comment: So what is the specific compile-time error then?

Comment: "is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener"

this give me the error a[i][j].mouseClicked(null,i,j);, but without i and j, works